# Python regex find sequence of 3 numbers followed by specific string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a regex pattern which matches three numbers separated by a single comma and whitespace, but I now want the pattern to find either " MHz" or " GHz" after these numbers.

I've tried a few patterns but none have worked

```
failed_patterns = [r'(\d+\, \d+\, \d+\s*Hz)',
                   r'(\d+\, \d+\, \d+\s*Hz)',
                   r'(\d+\, \d+\, \d+*Hz)']

# basic pattern
pattern = r'(\d+\, \d+\, \d+)'
string = '915, 868, 433 MHz'
re.findall(pattern, string)
# output: ['915, 868, 433']
```

Regular expressions are still quite new to me, so I'd hugely appreciate if someone could let me know where I went wrong and how I can change my pattern to get the result I need

Comment: You have not actually tried adding `M` or `G` to the patterns, have you? Try `re.findall(r'\d+, \d+, \d+\s*[GM]?Hz',  string)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cxxRn0/2).

Comment: I didn't know how I would do that. I'm still confused about when to use brackets or why I'm using brackets

Comment: `[...]` is a character class, it matches any char(s)/char  ranges listed inside it. `?` makes it optional.

Comment: Take a look at [Regexr](https://regexr.com/) - it's a good site I often use for regex development \ testing \ reference.

Comment: "Regular expressions are still quite new to me" Did you try searching for tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern works on your test example: `r'(\d{0,3}, \d{0,3}, \d{0,3} [MG]Hz)'`

Comment: It might not always be numbers consisting of 3 digits

Comment: @kynnem you are correct. this will find numbers *up to* 3 digits long, (using {m,n} will denotes a substring of at least length *m* up to length *n*) which is what I assumed you were intending. Also, be sure to checkout [pythex](http://pythex.org), which is useful for testing, cheatsheet, etc.

Comment: @kynnem also, [Chapter 7](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter7/) of Automate the Boring Stuff with Python provides a very beginner-friendly introduction to regex

Comment: It is also best practice to specify the lower boundary in a limiting quantifier, `{,3}` is better written as `{0,3}`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did not know that! Thank you for correcting me. I have updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

you can create two groups, one for the sequence of three numbers, and the second for the unit

```
import re
pattern =  r'(\d+, \d+, \d+) ([MG]Hz)'
string = '915, 868, 433 MHz'
list_match =re.findall(pattern, string)
for match in list_match:
    print("numbers: {} and unit: {}".format(match[0], match[1]))
```

output:

```
numbers: 915, 868, 433 and unit: MHz
```

Answer (score 1):

Pattern `r"\d+(, | [MG]Hz)"` will match all numbers with comma and additional whitespace next to it with MHz or GHz at the end.

`r""`: raw string notation for Python to escape special characters inside of regex
`\d+`: equal to `[0-9]`, matches any sequence of digits (1 or more) (`\d` mathes a singe digit)
`()`: capturing group, without it regex will try to find just the digit sequence + comma and just the whitespace + M/GHz combination
`, | [MG]Hz`: matches combination either (`,` ) or ( `GHz` or  `MHz`).